# Filter array of objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm using Python to dig through a pretty big project and dig up information about it. I'm able to create an array of `ProjectFile`s, however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to filter it.

```
class ProjectFile:
    def __init__(self, filename: str,
                 number_of_lines: int,
                 language: str,
                 repo: str,
                 size: int):
        self.filename = filename
        self.number_of_lines = number_of_lines
        self.language = language
        self.repo = repo
        self.size = size
```

How would I filter an array of `ProjectFile` objects for a specific `repo`?

For instance, let's say I wanted to filter for objects whose `repo` property is `SomeCocoapod`.

I've looked for examples of `filter`, but everything I've found uses simple examples like lists of `str` or `int`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can select attributes of a class using the dot notation.

Suppose `arr` is an array of ProjectFile objects. Now you filter for SomeCocoapod using.

```
filter(lambda p: p.repo == "SomeCocoapod", arr)
```

NB: This returns a filter object, which is a generator. To have a filtered list back you can wrap it in a list constructor.

As a very Pythonic alternative you can use list comprehensions:

```
filtered_arr = [p for p in arr if p.repo == "SomeCocoapod"]
```

Comment: Awesome! On filtering with `lambda`, I needed to wrap the filter in a `list` and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you had this simple list of two `ProjectFile` objects:

```
projects = [
    ProjectFile(
        filename="test1.txt",
        number_of_lines=1,
        language="English",
        repo="repo1",
        size=1,
    ),
    ProjectFile(
        filename="test2.txt", 
        number_of_lines=2, 
        language="German", 
        repo="repo2", 
        size=2
    ),
]
```

You could then filter out `repo1` using the `repo` attribute inside a [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html):

```
filtered = [project for project in projects if project.repo == "repo1"]
```

The above assumes you have overriden `__str__` or `__repr__` inside your `ProjectFile` class to give you a string representation of the filtered objects. Otherwise you will get something like `[<__main__.ProjectFile object at 0x000001E879278160>]` returned(which is fine if that's what you want to see). You can have a look at [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print) for more information.